# Android: Gradle: Change versionCode by custom task

Tags: android, gradle

here my app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2.3"
    }
}
```

I need before run task `assembleDebug` to increment **versionCode**.
So, if I understand correctly, I need to write custom Gradle task that increment **versionCode**. Is I'm right?

Is it possible to do this task?

Comment: Why would you want this? The version code is for Play Store and debug builds cannot be uploaded there.  You really want every build to have a different code? You will be building 1000's of times during development.

Comment: No I will increment versionCode when upload to Beta (CrashLytics). This is platform for our QA.I upload to Beta not very often (not after every commit). Maybe once in two weeks. So I need increment "versionCode" before upload to Beta.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. Store your version code somewhere. For example, create a `version.properties` file under your app module folder add the following into it:

```
VERSION_CODE=28
```

Create a Gradle file under your app module folder e.g. `devops.gradle` and add the following:

```
ext.getIncrementedVersionCode = {
    List<String> runTasks = gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames();
    def code = 1
    def versionPropsFile = file("$projectDir/version.properties")

    // get the old version code
    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        Properties versionProps = new Properties()
        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
        code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger()
        println "available version code = " + code

        for (String item : runTasks) {
            //TODO your gradle task comes here which will be executed
            if (item.contains("assembleDebug")) {
                println "Doing intermediate release.. incrementing the version code"
                code = code + 1
                versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] = code.toString()
                versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
                println "new version code= " + code
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }
    return code
}
```

Then change your`build.gradle`(app) like this:

```
...
apply from: 'devops.gradle'
    
android {
        ...
        defaultConfig {
            ...
            def yourVersionCode = getIncrementedVersionCode()
            versionCode yourVersionCode
           ...
        }
```

Now whenver you run `gradlew assembleDebug` your version code should be auto-incremented.